# Twig {% spaceless %} if a variable is true

Tags: twig

In Twig template, can I add the `{% spaceless %}` tag within an `if` statement?

For example,

```
{% if project.debug == true %} {% spaceless %} {% endif %}
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang='en'>
...
</html>
{% if project.debug == true %} {% endspaceless %} {% endif %}
```

This will throw an error "Twig_Error_Syntax -- Unexpected "endif" tag (expecting closing tag for the "spaceless" tag defined near line 1)."

Comment: Not sure why you want to toggle this? If this is for debug purposes then just use the "inspect element" tool of your browser as this delivers a formated layout of your source code

Comment: @DarkBee During debug, I may want to see the original spacing to figure out which element does not have a closing tag.

Comment: Perhaps you can have a look over [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13303/use-twigs-spaceless-tag-only-under-certain-conditionshttps://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13303/use-twigs-spaceless-tag-only-under-certain-conditions)